# How to create non-mapped derived CV class from UploadFile class

Tags: php, symfony

I have a CV class that is **not mapped**.CVs are not stored in database.Each CV should be uploaded from the signed in User where the CV object must contain a property owner(the logged in user who will be sending it).I did browse symfony documentation but it is shown only for single property in a whole different class that belongs to some UploadFile class.What I want is to create new CV class that probably extends UploadFile but have one extra field about the owner who we get from the current session.

How could I do it, so when the User upload a CV (Word Document) to happen all above?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've created non-mapped CV class that extends UploadFile but when I create an instance it wants some parameters because of the UploadFile's constructor.I am confused and I do not know what to try.That is the reason I am asking.

Comment: Is it UploadFile or UploadedFile? Please share your CV class with us and point us to your UploadFile class so that we know what you are talking about